# laravel in a subfolder - broken routes

Tags: apache, laravel

I am trying to reloacte my laravel application to a subfolder.

My main page is loading correctly at mysite.com/folder but when I try to login it goes to mysite.com/auth/login which returns a 404 error.

How can i change it so all of the routes will add the /folder so for example it will be mysite.com/folder/auth/login?

I have apache2 web server and the public folder is in *webroot/folder* and the rest of the files are on the same level as webroot in another folder

I followedthis to get to the stage im at currently : 
https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your RewriteBase in the .htaccess file located in the public folder. If you currently have `RewriteBase /` you probably should write `RewriteBase /folder/` instead.